# I don't think W/O replacement events are dependent.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

[image]

Let say there're cards numbered 1 to 10. P(A) is the probability you pick a card whose number is the multiple of 2. P(B) is the probability you pick a card whose number is the multiple of 5. So now you draw two cards without replacement. You don't place the first card you just drew back in the original deck. Then, you draw again from that 9 remaining cards.

In the picture, P(A) is shown as the ordered pairs colored red, and P(B) is shown as the ordered pairs shaded with light blue.

Then I counted them all.

1. P(A) = (9+9+9+9+9) / (100-10) = 45/90 = 1/2
2. P(B) = (9+9) / (100-10) = 18/90 = 1/5
3. P(A∩B) = 9 / 90 = 1/10

So here, I found out that P(A∩B) is actually the multiple of P(A) and P(B), which shouldn't be if they are dependent, meaning they are independent. I've also found out, in a different model, that the probabilities could be dependent each other in the case of W/O replacement such as this one.

I know events with replacements are independent. But it feels like events without replacements doesn't mean dependency. It's more like the case of contraposition of the first one. Events with replacements mean independent, which means, by the contraposition rule, dependent events are the ones done without replacements.

But all the other internet pages say like "if they are done without replacement, then they are dependent". This claim is so prevalent. But one of us, they or I, must be wrong. What am I missing here?

Comment: There is a difference between "the sequence of steps is dependent on the prior steps" and "these events are independent, meaning that they satisfy a certain equation". It's slightly unfortunate they both use the word "dependent", so that could be confusing. IE events which happen in sequence need not be dependent events. EG Flipping a coin and then tossing a dice are sequential events that are also independent.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I originally posted like P(A) is the probability of drawing the first card and having a number that's the multiple of 2, and P(B) is the second one. But I edited it because I don't think there's any differences

Comment: $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ **will** change for the second card.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel how do they change?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Let say you do the case A first, and then case B. If you draw 5 or 10 in your first drawing, P(B) is 2/10 times 1/9. And if you didn't draw 5 or 10 in your first drawing, P(B) is 8/10 times 2/9. If you sum two of them, you get (2/90) + (16/90) = 18/90 = 1/5, which is the same with just drawing 5 or 10 out of 10 cards = 2/10 = 1/5.

Comment: Please see my answer. Sampling without replacement is _usually_ dependent, but this problem as you formulated it originally furnishes an exception to the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version of your question, $P(A)$ only applied to the first card and $P(B)$ only applied to the second card. In that case, your workings are correct: $P(A)=\frac12,P(B)=\frac15,P(A\cap B)=\frac1{10}=P(A)P(B)$.

However, you then made this comment:

> Let say you do the case A first, and then case B. If you draw 5 or 10 in your first drawing, P(B) is 2/10 times 1/9. And if you didn't draw 5 or 10 in your first drawing, P(B) is 8/10 times 2/9.

This suggests an alternate interpretation: $P(A)$ is the probability of picking *at least one even card from the two draws*, $P(B)$ is the probability of picking *at least one multiple-of-$5$ card from the two draws*.

Then $P(A)$ is the complement of the probability that you don't pick an even card in either draw:
$$1-\frac5{10}\cdot\frac49=\frac79$$
$P(B)$ is similar, the complement of the probability of not picking a multiple-of-$5$ card in either draw:
$$1-\frac8{10}\cdot\frac79=\frac{17}{45}$$
$P(A\cap B)$ is the probability of picking one multiple-of-$5$ card and one even card:
$$\frac{2(2\cdot5-1)}{90}=\frac15$$
(There are $2$ ways to pick the multiple-of-$5$ card and $5$ ways to pick the even card, but then subtract $1$ for the impossible $(10,10)$ case. Then there are $2$ ways in which those cards can be drawn out, out of $90$ possible draws.)

Clearly, with this interpretation, $P(A\cap B)\ne P(A)P(B)$. Thus you cannot say straight away that "events that arise from sampling without replacement are dependent" – *usually* this is true, but your original formulation is a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

first, "with\without replacement" always appears with "sampling" 。I think the event A and event B you described is not sampling itself.

Normally, if P(A=i) is the probability you pick a card whose number is i,P(B=j) is the probability you pick a card whose number is j. apperantly,  P(B|A) != P(B) without replacement.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I get it what you mean, but I didn't mean "normally". I wrote I found both cases where it's a dependent case and a independent case w/o replacement respectively. I'm saying, every other pages says it like "w/o replacement always means dependent" and I feel it's wrong.

Comment: @user800956 I mean we should focus on "sampling", beacause "w/o replacement always means dependent" always is "In sampling w/o replacement, the two sample values aren't independent".  so i think that the independent case you described can not be the counter example of "w/o replacement always means dependent", because you just eaxmple only one situation not all situation of sampling.

Comment: Would you please explain why events A and B are not sampling? Is your term, "sampling", a topic from statistics? I didn't study that far yet. I only studied probabilities as far as something like Bayes' theorem.

Comment: @user800956 I think events A and events B just a possible result of sampling, and there are many other result of the sampling(e.g. A is the event we pick 1 ,B is the event we pick 2) . In my opinion,  "w/o replacement always means dependent" has the same mean as "In sampling w/o replacement,we can find some event A and event B  that they are depend", but i can't find the formal defination.

Answer (score -1):

A=the first card is even;

B=the second card is 5 or 10.

$P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$ as you said, but $P(B)=P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap A^C)=P(A)P(B|A)+P(b\cap A^C)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{5}+\frac{4}{5} \frac{2}{9}+\frac{1}{5} \frac{1}{9} =\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{3}{10}$

I hope no errors were made.

Comment: Thanks, but I think P(B│A^c) is not 4/5. P(B│A^c) means 5 or 10 out of odd numbers, which means (the number of odd number among 5 and 10) / (the number of odd numbers 1 through 10) = 1/5. That makes P(B) = (1/2)(1/5) + (1/2)(1/5) = 1/5, which is the same with just drawing 5 or 10 out of 1 to 10.

Comment: Actually, given $A^C$ we have now 4 even and 5 odd numbers left, so $P(B\cup A^C) =\frac{4}{5} \frac{2}{9}+\frac{1}{5} \frac{1}{9} =\frac{1}{5}$ so $P(B) =\frac{3}{10}$